# Mongodump query error

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

```
mongodump --username user --password password --db db --collection collection --query '{$and: [{"id": "ABCD"}, {"sz": {$gt: NumberLong(100)}}]}' --out dump
```

When executed, `mongodump` complained with:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:63
```

If I escape the `$and` and `$gt` clauses:

```
mongodump --username user --password password --db db --collection collection --query '{\$and: [{"id": "ABCD"}, {"sz": {\$gt: NumberLong(100)}}]}' --out dump
```

It will instead complain with

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: First character in field must be [A-Za-z$_]: offset:1
```

This query runs successfully on `mongodb` shell, I can't see why I can't use it as a `--query` parameter in `mongodump`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your $and clause is not needed. 
`{a: 'a', b: 'b'}` is the same as `$and : [{a: 'a'}, {b: 'b'}]`.

You also do not need to use `"id"`, you can just write `id`, the same for `NumberLong`.

So I would rewrite it as `... --query '{id: "ABCD", sz: {$gt: 100}}' --out dump` which works (you do not to escape $ if you are in a single quotes).